# Reference a library built in .NET 4.5.1 from a .NET 4.0 project (VSTO)

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto

I am building an Outlook 2010 VSTO. The highest framework allowed by Microsoft for this is 4.0. I have 3rd party libraries that I have to use, but they were built in .NET 4.5.1. With that said I can't reference the needed libraries.

I have no idea how to work around this. I have tried creating and referencing a second project that targets the updated framework to run my calls through, but because the second projects framework is a higher version, the VSTO can't see it during runtime.

Does anybody have any ideas as to how I can communicate with these libraries? I should note that all the machines that will use this will have the .NET 4.5.1 Framework.

Comment: You simply cannot. Have to find a .NET 4.0 compatible library.

Comment: Updating Office is the only solution with a warranty.  It's not like you can't hack around it, simply start the project by selecting 4.0 and then change it after the project is created.  Probably works fine, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a third-party library for the .net framework 4.0.

Also you may consider developing a shared COM add-in instead of VSTO. Or just use [Add-in Express](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/index.php) which supports targeting .net 4.5.